# Hadoop mapreduce wordcount-java.io.IOException: Job failed

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I got the following exception while trying to execute hadoop mapreduce program.

> java.io.IOException: Job failed!
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873)
> at WordCount1Driver.main(WordCount1Driver.java:45)

**WordCount1Driver.java**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount1Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    JobClient my_client = new JobClient();
    // Create a configuration object for the job
    JobConf job_conf = new JobConf(WordCount1Driver.class);

    // Set a name of the Job
    job_conf.setJobName("Word Count1");

    // Specify data type of output key and value
    job_conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job_conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // Specify names of Mapper and Reducer Class
    job_conf.setMapperClass(WordCount1Mapper.class);
    job_conf.setReducerClass(WordCount1Reducer.class);

    // Specify formats of the data type of Input and output
    job_conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    job_conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    // Set input and output directories using command line arguments, 
    //arg[0] = name of input directory on HDFS, and arg[1] =  name of output directory to be created to store the output file.
    
    //FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job_conf, new Path(args[0]));
    //FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job_conf, new Path(args[1]));
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job_conf, new Path("D:\\program files\\eclipse\\WordCount\\input.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job_conf, new Path("D:\\program files\\eclipse\\WordCount\\output"));
    
    my_client.setConf(job_conf);
    try {
        // Run the job 
        JobClient.runJob(job_conf);
        System.out.println("WordCount1 OK");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**WordCount1Mapper.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

 public class WordCount1Mapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
private Text word = new Text();
private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

    String valueString = value.toString();
    String[] SingleCountryData = valueString.split(" ");
    output.collect(new Text(SingleCountryData[7]), one);
    
    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
      }
  }
}
```

**WordCount1Reducer.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

public class WordCount1Reducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text t_key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        Text key = t_key;
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            // replace type of value with the actual type of our value
            IntWritable value = (IntWritable) values.next();
            sum += value.get();         
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

why does that exception occur?

Comment: 1) The really error message is in the YARN UI logs. 2) Your input path should be an HDFS path, not a `D:` drive folder 3) Are you required to learn Mapreduce? No one really writes it anymore due to the prevalence of higher level tools

Comment: I required to learn Mapreduce, and I don't know how to fix it , can you help me fix ???

Comment: It's not clear what the actual error message is, but like I said, giving the D drive path is not correct. It needs to be an HDFS path, not a Windows path

Comment: I do have some sample codes here, you could try modifying to your needs https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox

Comment: I executed mapreducer by eclipse on window 10 and even when i changed arg in configurations then it doesn't work. I also executed by cmd but it's even create folder output but don't have anything in that

Comment: when i click in "JobClient.java:873" then notice is "source not found the jar file hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3 has no source attachment" . In spite of the jar file hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3 exist

Comment: Where you able to run the code I linked to? What **exactly** did you change? Are you still trying to use Program Files path? Why? Dont use Eclipse to run. Create a fat JAR and use `hadoop jar` command since that is what you'd use against an actual Hadoop cluster. Also, that JAR is not the Hadoop source code, and its unclear why you would want to browse the source code when your error is elsewhere